# Toggle TWO Drop Down Panels

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using two panels at the top of my web page that drop down:  "Fast Quote" and "Client Login".  Can someone show me how to alter my code so that ONLY ONE panel is open at one time?  Example:  If "Client Login" is open and the user clicks on "Fast Quote", the "Client Login" should close and the "Fast Quote" drops down.

Here is my website:  http://www.ubspack.com

CODE:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".btn-slide").click(function(){
  $("#panel_quote").slideToggle("slow");
  $(this).toggleClass("closeQ"); return false;
 });
 });



  $(document).ready(function(){
 $(".btn-slide2").click(function(){
  $("#panel_login").slideToggle("slow");
  $(this).toggleClass("closeL"); return false;
 });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you would just close the other panel in your click handlers.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".btn-slide").click(function(){
    $("#panel_quote").slideToggle("slow");
    $(this).toggleClass("closeQ"); 
    $("#panel_login").slideUp();
    return false;
  });

  $(".btn-slide2").click(function(){
    $("#panel_login").slideToggle("slow");
    $(this).toggleClass("closeL"); 
    $("#panel_quote").slideUp();
    return false;
  });
});
```

Comment: I used your code and I'm a bit confused on the toggle.  You can see it.

Comment: which part is confusing you?  all I added was the `.slideUp()` calls.

Comment: Thank you works great, but I'm trying to figure out how to toogle the image links:  $(this).toggleClass("closeQ"); and $(this).toggleClass("closeQ"); when panel returns....

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
     $(".btn-slide").click(function(){
          return Toggle()
     });

     $(".btn-slide2").click(function(){
          return Toggle()
     });

    });

function Toggle() {
     $(".btn-slide1").toggleClass("closeQ");
     $(".btn-slide2").toggleClass("closeL");
}
```

Calling `Toggle()` will toggle both classes at the same time - then it's simply a case of making sure one has the class applied to start with...

Comment: hence "hen it's simply a case of making sure one has the class applied to start with..." :)